# Using .SpecialCells

Tags: vba, excel

I have a line of code that converts any cells contain #DIV/O error with 0. Which is idealy, apart from when there is no #DIV/o error found in range. When this is that case i get a run time error informing me that there is none found and then I can't move past this.

Is there a way to pass over this issue?

The code goes as follows

```
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors)

          For Each rCell In rng
          If rCell.Value = CVErr(xlErrDiv0) Then
          rCell.Value = 0
          End If
          Next
```

I have tried to play around using `NullString` & `For loops` but to no avail.

Any help would be  greatful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to overcome the issue is to add `ErrorHandler` like the one below:

```
Sub DivByZero()
On Error GoTo ErrHandler:
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors)

For Each rCell In rng
    If rCell.Value = CVErr(xlErrDiv0) Then
        rCell.Value = 0
    End If
Next

ErrHandler:
If Err.Number = 1004 Then
    Exit Sub
End If

End Sub
```